# Multer File Validation for upload.fields

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Trying to Implement Multer Validation to allow only Image/Video's Files
I'm Currently using upload.fields As an Middleware.
I Couldn't Find Any Docs About Error Handling when using upload.fields as an middleware

Found only this :
https://gist.github.com/huynhsamha/348722d47ee457454688698ff77fee1a